# Why does my server choke when a header has a "\n" character but not an "\r" character?

Tags: php, http-headers

I just finished debugging an issue for a project where an HTTP 500 would go up whenever Drupal attempted to send a file to download. Turned out that the server thought the Content-Disposition header was bad because of the filename attribute encoded the way RFC 2047 specifies, but it just wasn't having the \n. So I replaced n with r and now the server is more than happy.

So I'm wondering if this server treats \n different from \r and how I would be able to tell in the future and/or why \r would work and \n wouldn't?

**Edit:** The headers sent by the script:

```
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.17
Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 14 Nov 2012 20:43:20 +0000
ETag: "1352925800"
Content-Length: 1302854
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="=?UTF-8?B?UHJvUXVhbGl0ZSBNYW51ZWwgZGVzIHByb2dyYW1tZXMgcHLDqWFsYWJsZXMgMjA=?=
 =?UTF-8?B?MTAgYXZlYyBhbm5leGVzXzBfMC5wZGY=?="
Cache-Control: private
Content-type: application/pdf
```

Comment: which server? apache? nginx? iis?

Comment: i thought headers had to all end with <CR><LF>

Comment: @MarcB Apache running on FreeBSD.

Comment: @Dagon Yep, they are. RFC 2047 says encoded-words should also be separated by CRLF SPACE sequences.

Comment: Apache treats LF like CRLF, and apparently it's not O.K. with the use of CRLF+LWP to cause header folding inside a quoted-string. Who can blame it?

Comment: By the way, your statement that "the filename attribute" was "encoded the way RFC 2047 specifies" is a bit strange, since RFC 2047 explicitly states that "An 'encoded-word' MUST NOT appear within a 'quoted-string'" and that "An 'encoded-word' MUST NOT be used in parameter of a MIME Content-Type or Content-Disposition field". And even if we ignore those restrictions, your encoding still doesn't quite work, because header folding would remove the CRLF. (That is: you want the CRLF to serve double duty, for both header folding and encoding; but the one would prevent the other.)

Answer (score 1):

I assume here that you are talking about the line termination.

According to [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) HTTP headers should end with '\r\n' string (CRLF):

> HTTP/1.1 defines the sequence CR LF as the end-of-line marker for all
> protocol elements except the entity-body

...

```
generic-message = start-line
                  *(message-header CRLF)
                  CRLF
                  [ message-body ]
start-line      = Request-Line | Status-Line
```

That is what should terminate an HTTP header line. If you don't follow the specifications, the server can either choke or do something else it feels like doing, so irrelevant of the server, you should.

Comment: I saw that in [RFC2047](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt), but it seems to be just fine with chunks ending with "\r ", but not so much "\n " and that's what I'm really curious about.

Comment: @mikemcg that's just undefined behaviour afaik. It can work "just fine", or it can choke - that's up to the implementation. Both `\r` and `\n` are still wrong by themselves.

Comment: well there is the specs, then there is how any particulate piece of software decides to 'interpret' the specs

Comment: @eis Explicitly using "\r\n" in tandem seems to cause 500 errors as well, it's only \r that seems to work. Is there any way to determine the behaviour of control characters or something like that?

Comment: @mikemcg can you add an example HTTP request/response on the question itself that seems to cause the 500 error?